# How to write a unix script that gets notified with IMAP IDLE from Gmail?

Tags: linux, unix, gmail, imap

I'm looking for a way to get notified in my unix system for new email. I know gmail supports IMAP IDLE, what is the best way to make use of that feature? Any programming language is fine, as long as it is supported in linux/unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not used this, but for Perl the [Mail::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/~plobbes/Mail-IMAPClient-3.32/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod) module seems to support IDLE.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest python and **IMAPClient** by Menno Smits.

http://imapclient.readthedocs.org